# pandas update on select columns and track change date

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and need to update certain columns in the first with corresponding values in the second, and then change a column of dates to reflect that there was a change.

```
today = datetime.datetime.today().date()

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['alpha','foo','buzz','fox',datetime.date(2017,5,31),np.nan],['Beta','foo','flop','cat',datetime.date(2017,8,11),datetime.date(2017,9,19)],
                   ['Gamma','bar','honk','sheep',datetime.date(2017,8,12),np.nan],['omega','bar','growl','dog',datetime.date(2017,2,23),datetime.date(2017,3,2)]], 
                   columns = ['type','col1','col2','enteredCol','CreationDate','lastUpdateDate']).set_index(['type'])

print df1

      col1   col2 enteredCol CreationDate lastUpdateDate
type                                                    
alpha  foo   buzz        fox   2017-05-31            NaN
Beta   foo   flop        cat   2017-08-11     2017-09-19
Gamma  bar   honk      sheep   2017-08-12            NaN
omega  bar  growl        dog   2017-02-23     2017-03-02


df2 = pd.DataFrame([['alpha','bar','buzz'],['Beta','foo','twist'],['Gamma','bar','honk']], columns = ['type','col1','col2']).set_index(['type'])

print df2
      col1   col2
type             
alpha  bar   buzz
Beta   foo  twist
Gamma  bar   honk
```

Where col1 or col2 are different in df2, I need to update the corresponding values in df1. If a change is made, the lastUpdateDate needs to be set to today's date

```
#run update on col1 and col2 - if updated, change lastUpdateDate to today's date

print df_out

      col1   col2 enteredCol CreationDate lastUpdateDate
type                                                    
alpha  bar   buzz        fox   2017-05-31     2017-10-31
Beta   foo  twist        cat   2017-08-11     2017-10-31
Gamma  bar   honk      sheep   2017-08-12            NaN
omega  bar  growl        dog   2017-02-23     2017-03-0
```

Thoughts on how I can do this? I could manually merge each of the changed columns and compare, but there are many columns I need to check. df.update() doesn't give a way to note that the values have been changed, or I could use that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `combine_first` then boolean indexing:

```
df_out = df2.combine_first(df1)

df_out.loc[~df1[['col1','col2']].eq(df_out[['col1','col2']]).all(1),'lastUpdateDate'] = today

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
      CreationDate col1   col2 enteredCol lastUpdateDate
type                                                    
Beta    2017-08-11  foo  twist        cat     2017-10-31
Gamma   2017-08-12  bar   honk      sheep            NaN
alpha   2017-05-31  bar   buzz        fox     2017-10-31
omega   2017-02-23  bar  growl        dog     2017-03-02
```

Comment: Nice one  :-) LOL

Comment: Just miss you :-) and saw you back then laugh LOL

Answer (score -1):

I'm struggling a little to parse your question.
But if I read it correctly, just use a mask.

```
for col in ['col1','col2']:
    to_update = df1[col] != df2[col]
    df1.loc[to_update,col] = df2.loc[to_update,col]
    df1.loc[to_update,'lastUpdateDate'] = todays_date
```

where todays_date is the string formatted date